# Como passar dados de uma atividade para um dialogFragment?

Tags: c#, android

Na minha atividade eu tenho isto:

```
mBtnSignUp.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                //Pull up dialog
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new dialog_SignUp();
                signUpDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");

                signUpDialog.mOnSignUpComplete += signUpDialog_mOnSignUpComplete;
            };
void signUpDialog_mOnSignUpComplete (object sender, OnSignUpEventArgs e)
        {

            Thread thread = new Thread (ActLikeARequest);
            thread.Start ();


        }
        private void ActLikeARequest()
        {

            Thread.Sleep (3000);
        }
```

E no `Dialog` tenho:

```
public class OnSignUpEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string mFirstName;
        private string mEmail;
        private string mPassword;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get{ return mFirstName; }
            set{ mFirstName=value;}

        }
        public string Email
        {
            get{ return mEmail; }
            set{ mEmail=value;}

        }
        public string Password
        {
            get{ return mPassword; }
            set{ mPassword=value;}

        }

        public OnSignUpEventArgs (string firstName, string email, string password) : base()
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
        }

    }

    class dialog_SignUp:DialogFragment
    {
        private Button mBtnSignUp;
        private EditText mFirstName;
        private EditText mEmail;
        private EditText mPassword;

        public event EventHandler<OnSignUpEventArgs> mOnSignUpComplete;


        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.dialog_sign_up, container, false);

            mBtnSignUp = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnDialogEmail);
            mFirstName = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
            mEmail = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            mPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.txtPassword);

            mBtnSignUp.Click += mBtnSignUp_Click;



            return view;
        }

        void mBtnSignUp_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //User has clicked the sign up button

            mOnSignUpComplete.Invoke (this, new OnSignUpEventArgs(mFirstName.Text, mEmail.Text, mPassword.Text));
            this.Dismiss ();

        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //Sets the title bar to invisible
            base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation; //Set the animation
        }
    }
```

A questão é, como é que eu passo dados da minha atividade (strings) para o meu `Dialog`, de forma a quando este é chamado, as `TextViews (mFirstName, mEmail, mPassword)` fiquem com o `Text = *strings passadas*`?

Comment: Acho que dentro mesmo da sua classe `dialog_SignUp` você pode criar um construtor dela que receba 3 argumentos, os quais no `OnCreateView` você vai usar para preencher estes campos. Você já fez essa tentativa?

Comment: @CesarMiguel agora que disse, tentei e resultou Obrigado! Poste como resposta para ganharmos reputação. Abraço

Comment: @RuiQuaresma, não fui eu que respondi :P

Comment: @CesarMiguel ta a resposta no comentario ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ter na sua própria classe `dialog_SignUp` um construtor que receba estes valores:

```
class dialog_SignUp:DialogFragment {
    private string firstName;
    private string email;
    private string password;

    public dialog_SignUp(string pName, string pEmail, string pPassword) {
        firstName = pName;
        email = pEmail;
        password = pPassword;
    }
}
```

Dentro desta classe, no método `OnCreateView`, atribua aos campos de texto:

```
mFirstName.setText(firstName);
mEmail.setText(email);
mPassword.setText(password);
```

E com isso, no momento que você instanciar esta classe você passa os 3 argumentos para serem preenchidos em seus devidos campos.

Comment: é isso mesmo, já deu, Obrigado